# Phpunit overriding variable in .env

Tags: php, phpunit, automated-tests, laravel-5.1

In my .env file of a laravel 5.1 project i have set the APP_ENV to local, But when i run the test from the terminal the with

```
vendor/bin/phpunit
```

the debug and die on

```
dd(env(APP_ENV));
```

gives me "testing".

I Have dont a good research on this, tried using the following ways -

- trying to set the APP_ENV=local pipelining vendor/bin/phpunit form the cli.
- Trying to add env variable in the phpunit.xml file`<env name="APP_ENV" value="local" override="true">` (dosent seem to override though)
- adding a .env.testing file and setting the APP_ENV=local
- in the testCase.php file where the application autoloads `$app->loadEnvironmentFrom('.env.testing');`

none of the above methods give me the expected result rather everytime i run the test give APP_ENV as "testing".

Not able to trace where is phpunit setting this variable from.
Pls help out!

Comment: You usually don't want the env to be local when you are _testing_ with phpunit. You want to be able to differentiate between testing and local so you can use mock classes for things like DB calls etc.

Comment: the point is that i am using an integration server which runs the test using phpunit, and the DB config is different there, Because of this i need to use the env variable to be different in local dev machine and the integration server envirironment. But i dont kno how it somehow overrides everything and sets the APP_ENV to "testing" always

Answer (score -3):

In vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php search for putenv('APP_ENV=testing'); try to change this to local.
This should work for you, though it is not advisable.

Comment: disturbing the underlying architecture is not a good thing to do. Rather i think ill try to override the trait which is writing in the env for every instance. Anyways thank for the input